# cpanel .htaccess is not redirecting to HTTPS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl, cpanel

I'm missing something simple I'm sure, some insight would be very helpful.  I am working on setting up web site on a vps using cpanel.  I'm trying to get it to always redirect to https instead having both available, I can do this without cpanel, but seem to be stumped when cpanel gets involved.  I saw this, but it was zero help 
   https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9770/38/how-to-force-https-using-htaccess-file-in-cpanel

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: So what is your actual issue?

Comment: Certainly you should place the https redirection _before_ any internal rewriting rules.

Comment: Actual issue is the title "cpanel .htaccess is not redirecting to HTTPS" and I have tried that as well. Thank you for the attempt.

Comment: Are you really sure that other rewriting rule is actually working? Or could it be that your dynamic configuration is ignored completely? Have you enabled such files using the `AllowOverride` directive? Is the rewriting module loaded into your http server? Does your http servers error log file show any entries? If so post them please.

Comment: Yes I'm sure.. I said it was working before cpanel.  If I click a link it changes to https, but initial site load doesn't automatically change to https. No logs don't show anything... I checked those before I posted this question is it would be the ideal place to find the issue.

Comment: Ah, that is completely new information! Why didn't you say so in the question? I _bet_ this is a simple caching issue then: clear your browsers cache and retry the request.

Comment: Oh, and wait a minute, you changed your rewriting condition! Now it suddenly says `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on`, before it said `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`. With the current notation _certainly_ no redirection will ever get applied. _And_ any page already requested via http will result in an endless loop.

Comment: Yeah I changed it because I realized it was wrong. Didn't help matters any.

Comment: I tried clearing the cache in the browser and no help.

Comment: _Now_ it is wrong. If https is already set, you do _not_ want to rewrite to https. You want to rewrite if https is _off_.

Comment: Same problem, initial site load is not https.

Comment: Something is fishy here. Please enable rewrite logging and raise the log level to 5 or 6. Monitor your rewrite log file and repeat your initial site load doing a _deep reload_ in your browser.

Comment: I agree, I don't think it's a rewrite issue at all, I think it's a problem in cpanel configuration.  I'll find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing your `RewriteRule` like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L,NE]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before you test this. I've set the flag to `R`, but if you're happy with the redirection then change it to `R=301` as that will make it a permanent redirect.

Comment: This may help some, but I found out it's just the initial load of the site.  If you click a link to anther page it will change to HTTPS.. So I'm missing something somewhere.

Comment: A redirection to a URL _always_ is performed as an external redirection, no need for the `R` flag. Same applies for the `L` flag.

Answer (score 0):

You can always **use a different .htaccess rule** to redirect to HTTPS. I would re-write your .htaccess to the following (hardcoding your domain):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```